# file is encrypted or is not a database - IsoStoreSpy, sqlitestudio, visual studio 2015

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-mobile, sqlitestudio

i create an app in windows mobile 10. i used isoStoreSpy tool to download file from mobile, and i used SQLiteStudio to edit it. And then, i upload it to mobile and error:

[file is encrypted or is not a database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuu2I.png)

Comment: Let's see some code please :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fuu2I.png

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fuu2I.png
this is my code and error